# XMLHttpRequest.readyState

Tags: javascript, ajax

home.html

```
front page test
```

test.php

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="ajax.js"></SCRIPT>
<button type="button" onclick="callAJAX('home.html','displaydiv')">Click Me!</button>
<div id="displaydiv"></div>
```

ajax.js

```
function callAJAX(url, pageElement, callMessage) {
    document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = callMessage;
    try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* e.g. Firefox */
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            /* some versions IE */
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                /* some versions IE */
            } catch (E) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
    }

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {responseAJAX(pageElement);};     
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);

}

function responseAJAX(pageElement) {
    console.log(req.readyState);
    var output = '';
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
             output = req.responseText;
             document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = output;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is mainly from [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/AJAX-Understanding-AJAX-P101.html):

Questions:

1. according to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp), *onreadystatechange stores a function (or the name of a function) to be called automatically each time the readyState property changes* so when will `readyState` property change? after `req.send(null);`?
2. for this line: `console.log(req.readyState);` in chrome console, it shows: `1 2 3 4`, it does not output 0, is that because `0: request not initialized`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readyState changes in a few places, check out [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for more information.  req.readyState = 0 means that req.open() has not been called yet.

Also, depending on [what browsers you are trying to support with this code](http://caniuse.com/xhr2), you can look into using some of the features from [XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), including a req.onload() function that would change your code to:

```
function callAJAX(url, pageElement, callMessage) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(pageElement);
    elem.innerHTML = callMessage;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function() {
        elem.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    };     
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);
}
```